# How to remove check constraint in mysql workbench 8.0?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, alter-table, check-constraints

Can anyone give me the command to remove the check constraint in workbench please? I used `alter table details drop check details_chk_1;` but it isnt working. It shows error in drop command. pls help

Comment: Please add the output from show create table details as text to the question.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

This is working in my workbench 8.0

```
alter table TABLE_NAME drop check CHECK_NAME;
```

The name can be found by running any command on the column. For eg: I ran

```
alter table movies rename column Release_Year to  Year ;
```

which gave me this error

```
18:03:57    alter table movies rename column Release_Year to  Year  Error Code: 3959. Check constraint 'movies_chk_1' uses column 'Release_Year', hence column cannot be dropped or renamed.    0.000 sec
```

From here you can use the name of the constraint and paste it to resolve the error.
Here's the resolved response

```
18:04:14    alter table movies drop check movies_chk_1  0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.203 sec

18:10:17    alter table movies rename column Release_Year to  Year  0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.047 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try ALTER TABLE details ALTER CHECK details_chk_1 NOT ENFORCED;

Answer (score 0):

**ALTER TABLE student DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;**

you can set constraint name manually also ... but if you want to check constraint name which is auto set.. .then enter following query
show create table table_name;